# Trouble Promoting Windows Server 2019 to Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, rpc, windows-server-2019

I am trying to add an additional domain controller using Windows 2019 Standard in a Windows 2012 R2 environment.  As far as I can tell, this is supported by Microsoft.

When trying to promote the new server to a DC, I get an error that the wizard cannot gain access to the list of domains in the forest.  The extra information states that the RPC server is unavailable.  I have added temporary firewall rules to allow ALL inbound and outbound TCP and UDP traffic (just to see if I can get it to work), but that does not work.

[image: Screenshot of error]

I also verified many services are running on this machine as well as the "primary" domain controller.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, please make sure the DNS server on the NIC for that server is set correctly to the other DC. a ping domain.name should return a value

Comment: It is set correctly.